# How to detect browser tab change in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on angularjs, after log-in, when the user open multiple tabs and log-out in one of the tabs then in another tabs , how to log-out in another tabs also.

like facebook, if we log-out in one tab other in tabs get log-out.

How to achieve this..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Facebook has open WebSocket, so when you log out in one tab they can send a logout command in the other. another option is with service workers

Answer (score 0):

This requirement cannot be achieved using a client-side scripting language.
You need to maintain the session details on the server and as soon as a new login happens on the server, you need to update your client to log out of the other logged in page.

To achieve this, use web sockets and session handling technologies.